# Compare and merge data from two array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, data-structures

Hello everyone I am newbie in data structure, I have been practising few array operations in JavaScript. I want to do following

```
var classes = [{id : 1, class:'first'},{id : 2, class:'second'},{id : 3, class:'third'},{id : 4, class:'fourth'}]
var students =[{classId : 1, count:30}, {classId : 3, count:46}, {classId : 2, count:52}]
```

and I am expecting following output

```
classes = [
{id : 1, class:'first', count:30},
{id : 2, class:'second', count:52},
{id : 3, class:'third', count:46},
{id : 4, class:'fourth', count:0}

]
```

I have tried following code for same

```
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < students.length; j++) {

        if (classes[i]["id"] == students[j]["classId"]) {
            classes[i]["count"] = students[j]["count"]


        } else {
            classes[i]["count"] = 0
        }

        if (i == classes.length - 1) {
            console.log(classes);
        }

    }

}
```

But no luck, is there any better way other than for loop? can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combination:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Code snippet, possible solution:

```js
const classes = [{id : 1, class:'first'},{id : 2, class:'second'},{id : 3, class:'third'},{id : 4, class:'fourth'}]
const students =[{classId : 1, count:30}, {classId : 3, count:46}, {classId : 2, count:52}];

const result = classes.map(e => {
  const found = students.find(s => s.classId === e.id);
  return {
    ...e,
    count: found ? found.count : 0
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You so much!!! Coding is a real magic :) Can you suggest some reference videos or doc so I can learn more about it.

Comment: @Swapnil I suggest to check out [JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) topics first, trying to make a pet project like a to-do list app or something like that. That would help you understand more coding and programming maybe. There are lots of training materials out there. I hope this helps at least.

Answer (score 0):

try using this solution

```
for(let class in classes){
console.log(classes[class]);
}
```

what you are doing here is going through ever index of the array classes, and storing the index in class. then you `console.log` the index.